# Oscommerce >> Paypal > Shpping and handling fee

Tags: php, paypal, oscommerce

I have an `oscommerce` website. When we try to do a payment while using `PayPal` it will show `shipping and handling fee`

Can anyone help me to find out where `shipping and handling fee` is set in the code of `oscommerce`?

[image]

Comment: Sometimes it comes from your actual paypal account. If not - it will be in shipping modules.